# How to forward subdomain DNS to Windows Server DNS while keeping the parent in local zone

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, bind

I have a Bind9 (Ubuntu) as my primary DNS server in my lab environment and hosts zone files. I recently added Active Directory to the environment. My plan is to keep Bind9 as my Primary DNS and any queries related to the AD network should be forwarded to the Windows Server.

`named.conf.local`:

```
zone "example.local" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.example.local";
};

zone "16.172.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master; 
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.16.172";
};

zone "ad.lab.example.io" {
  type forward;
  forward only;
  forwarders { 172.16.1.9; };
};

zone "lab.example.io" {
       type master;
       file "/etc/bind/zones/db.lab.example.io";
};
```

By having the above configuration running, When I do a `nslookup` from a client, it fails any query to the AD subdomain `ad.lab.example.io`. But working for `lab.example.io`.

Eg: `nslookup testserver.ad.lab.example.io` gets the error `Non-existent domain`.
But `nslookup server1.lab.example.io` is providing the expected result.

But, if I comment out the last part in the conf file which is `zone "lab.example.io"`; then queries on the AD subdomain are working.

Eg: `nslookup testserver.ad.lab.example.io` is providing the expected result; but in this case, my queries to `server1.lab.example.io` are not resolving (as I commented out).

How should I achieve, to resolve
`lab.example.io` queries from local bind9 zone file;
and `ad.lab.example.io` queries should successfully forward to Windows Server `172.16.1.9`?

I tried different ways, by adding a forwarder statement to the `zone "lab.example.io"` but it didn't work out.

Thanks!